# How to change the textcolor in RGraph.Text canvas text element

Tags: html, canvas, rgraph

having a canvas element in my html page,
i can draw graphs, using the [rgraph](http://www.rgraph.net) library... 
Now i would like to add a certain text element on there
which i can do by printing it like this:

```
RGraph.Text(this.canvas.getContext("2d"), "Verdana", 8, 30, 125, 'TECHNOLOGY', "top", "left", false, 270, '#000000');
```

now, there is only 1 argument for color, and it's the text background color
i would need to change it's text color dynamically. does anyone know how to change the text color of that item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the RGraph methods (though not all) use whatever the current strokeStyle or fillStyle settings are. So for example:

```
context.fillStyle = 'red';
RGraph.Text(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

oh dear,
I was again way to fast in posting here.
this solution is simple, but default canvas, and not possible with the RGraph.Text() method itself, just initialize a context fillcolor.

```
myContext = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
myContext.setFillColor(255, 255, 0, 1.0); // you can add any RGBA values here...
RGraph.Text(/* arguments go here */);
```